# Ошибка: Trailling coma not allowed without surrounding parenthness

Tags: python, pyqt5, ui, pyside2

В программе QtDesigner создал файл, перекинул из формата `.ui` в `.py` , зашел в Visual Studio Code, и ничего не работает из за ошибки при `from PySide2.QtGui import QFontDatabase` выдает ошибку `Trailling coma not allowed without surrounding parenthness`

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from ui import Ui_Form
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QSize, QUrl, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont
from PySide2.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
from PySide2.QtGui import QRadialGradient
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(370, 426)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"height: 70px;\n"
"widght: 70px;\n"
"font-size: 14 px;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"borders: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   background-color: silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"   background-color:gold;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 331, 301))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.pushButton_3 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(u"pushButton_3")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 2, 2, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_6 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(u"pushButton_6")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_4 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(u"pushButton_4")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_7 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(u"pushButton_7")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_8 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_8.setObjectName(u"pushButton_8")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_9 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_9.setObjectName(u"pushButton_9")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 0, 2, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_5 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(u"pushButton_5")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_10 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_10.setObjectName(u"pushButton_10")

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 3, 1, 1, 1)

    self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"verticalLayoutWidget")
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(19, 9, 331, 61))
    self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
    self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
# setupUi

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
    self.pushButton_6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
    self.pushButton_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
    self.pushButton_7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
    self.pushButton_8.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
    self.pushButton_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
    self.pushButton_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
    self.pushButton_10.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
# retranslateUi
```

Comment: У вас ошибка из-за лишней запятой в импорте, посмотрите мой ответ. Импорт всех классов, хоть и поможет, но не относится к сути вашей проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите запятую в конце строки импорта:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
```

т.е.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap
```

Или добавив скобки:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import (QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет `Visual Studio` и `PySide2`.
У меня установлен `PyQt5`, но это практически одно и тоже, что и `PySide2`.

И если заменить

```
"widght: 70px;\n"
"borders: none;\n"
```

на

```
"width: 70px;\n"
"border: none;\n"
```

и запустить из терминала/CMD `python main.py`, то вот что получается.

Попробуйте установить свои импорты и запустить из консоли.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys

# PySide2
#from PySide2.QtCore import *
#from PySide2.QtGui import *
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

# PyQt5
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ? from ui import Ui_Form
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(370, 426)
        # ? "borders: none;\n"
        # ? "widght: 70px;\n"
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: #737373;\n"
"height: 70px;\n"
"width: 70px;\n"
"font-size: 14 px;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"border: none;\n"                 
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   background-color: silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"   background-color:gold;\n"
"}")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 331, 301))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.pushButton_3 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(u"pushButton_3")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_6 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(u"pushButton_6")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_4 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(u"pushButton_4")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_7 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(u"pushButton_7")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_8 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName(u"pushButton_8")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_9 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName(u"pushButton_9")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_5 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(u"pushButton_5")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_10 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName(u"pushButton_10")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
### +++       
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #99f;')

        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(19, 9, 331, 61))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]